# After redeploying of war file can't see the changes which are made

Tags: gradle, jboss, wildfly

Application was builded with gradle and deployed in Wildfly-9.0.1.Final.
Java class in which have the changes was recompiled.
At the gradle command prompt, I typed  'gradle clean deploy'.

Below is log of deploying. File which must be redeployed called directory.war.
Deleting a file does not help.

```
2015-11-11 10:13:57,804 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HQ221034: Waiting to obtain live lock
2015-11-11 10:13:57,804 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HQ221035: Live Server Obtained live lock
2015-11-11 10:13:57,864 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0001: Bound data source [java:/datasources/DirectoryDS]
2015-11-11 10:13:58,466 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Insanely Bad Elf' 7.2.3.Final
2015-11-11 10:13:58,575 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYMSG0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for hornetq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor-throughput acceptor
2015-11-11 10:13:58,585 INFO  [org.jboss.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSG0016: Registered HTTP upgrade for hornetq-remoting protocol handled by http-acceptor acceptor
2015-11-11 10:13:58,844 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HQ221007: Server is now live
2015-11-11 10:13:58,859 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) HQ221001: HornetQ Server version 2.4.7.Final (2.4.7.Final, 124) [e0163962-5c75-11e5-898f-bddf0d0aae9d] 
2015-11-11 10:13:59,030 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 72) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:/ConnectionFactory
2015-11-11 10:13:59,503 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0007: Registered connection factory java:/JmsXA
2015-11-11 10:13:59,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 74) WFLYCLINF0002: Started users cache from keycloak container
2015-11-11 10:13:59,662 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 75) WFLYCLINF0002: Started loginFailures cache from keycloak container
2015-11-11 10:13:59,687 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYCLINF0002: Started sessions cache from keycloak container
2015-11-11 10:13:59,704 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 73) WFLYCLINF0002: Started realms cache from keycloak container
2015-11-11 10:13:59,724 INFO  [org.hornetq.ra] (MSC service thread 1-4) HornetQ resource adaptor started
2015-11-11 10:13:59,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.services.resourceadapters.ResourceAdapterActivatorService$ResourceAdapterActivator] (MSC service thread 1-4) IJ020002: Deployed: file://RaActivatorhornetq-ra
2015-11-11 10:13:59,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYJCA0002: Bound JCA ConnectionFactory [java:/JmsXA]
2015-11-11 10:13:59,724 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (MSC service thread 1-2) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory
2015-11-11 10:13:59,976 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 81) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /modeshape-webdav
2015-11-11 10:14:00,220 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 79) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.DLQ
2015-11-11 10:14:00,264 INFO  [org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Load config from c:\wildfly-9.0.1.Final\standalone\configuration\keycloak-server.json
2015-11-11 10:14:00,265 INFO  [org.jboss.as.messaging] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYMSG0002: Bound messaging object to jndi name java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory
2015-11-11 10:14:00,271 INFO  [org.hornetq.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) HQ221003: trying to deploy queue jms.queue.ExpiryQueue
2015-11-11 10:14:02,363 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: keycloak-default
    ...]
2015-11-11 10:14:02,524 INFO  [org.hibernate.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.10.Final}
2015-11-11 10:14:02,529 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2015-11-11 10:14:02,532 INFO  [org.hibernate.cfg.Environment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2015-11-11 10:14:02,872 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2015-11-11 10:14:03,623 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2015-11-11 10:14:03,654 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2015-11-11 10:14:03,876 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (MSC service thread 1-3) WFLYJPA0002: Read persistence.xml for default
2015-11-11 10:14:04,296 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 1 of 2) Service 'directory.war#default'
2015-11-11 10:14:04,326 INFO  [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2015-11-11 10:14:04,330 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment directory.war
2015-11-11 10:14:04,408 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-11-11 10:14:04,432 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.1.3.Final
2015-11-11 10:14:04,533 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Railways in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Railways!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Railways
    java:app/directory/Railways!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Railways
    java:module/Railways!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Railways
    java:global/directory/Railways
    java:app/directory/Railways
    java:module/Railways

2015-11-11 10:14:04,535 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Countries in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Countries!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Countries
    java:app/directory/Countries!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Countries
    java:module/Countries!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Countries
    java:global/directory/Countries
    java:app/directory/Countries
    java:module/Countries

2015-11-11 10:14:04,537 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named AirAlliances in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/AirAlliances!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.AirAlliances
    java:app/directory/AirAlliances!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.AirAlliances
    java:module/AirAlliances!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.AirAlliances
    java:global/directory/AirAlliances
    java:app/directory/AirAlliances
    java:module/AirAlliances

2015-11-11 10:14:04,538 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named HotelChains in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/HotelChains!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.HotelChains
    java:app/directory/HotelChains!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.HotelChains
    java:module/HotelChains!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.HotelChains
    java:global/directory/HotelChains
    java:app/directory/HotelChains
    java:module/HotelChains

2015-11-11 10:14:04,545 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Locations in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Locations!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Locations
    java:app/directory/Locations!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Locations
    java:module/Locations!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Locations
    java:global/directory/Locations
    java:app/directory/Locations
    java:module/Locations

2015-11-11 10:14:04,557 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Airports in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Airports!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Airports
    java:app/directory/Airports!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Airports
    java:module/Airports!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Airports
    java:global/directory/Airports
    java:app/directory/Airports
    java:module/Airports

2015-11-11 10:14:04,569 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named RailStations in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/RailStations!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.RailStations
    java:app/directory/RailStations!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.RailStations
    java:module/RailStations!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.RailStations
    java:global/directory/RailStations
    java:app/directory/RailStations
    java:module/RailStations

2015-11-11 10:14:04,574 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named RailwayUnions in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/RailwayUnions!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.RailwayUnions
    java:app/directory/RailwayUnions!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.RailwayUnions
    java:module/RailwayUnions!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.RailwayUnions
    java:global/directory/RailwayUnions
    java:app/directory/RailwayUnions
    java:module/RailwayUnions

2015-11-11 10:14:04,588 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Areas in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Areas!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Areas
    java:app/directory/Areas!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Areas
    java:module/Areas!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Areas
    java:global/directory/Areas
    java:app/directory/Areas
    java:module/Areas

2015-11-11 10:14:04,631 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Places in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Places!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Places
    java:app/directory/Places!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Places
    java:module/Places!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Places
    java:global/directory/Places
    java:app/directory/Places
    java:module/Places

2015-11-11 10:14:04,634 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Hotels in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Hotels!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Hotels
    java:app/directory/Hotels!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Hotels
    java:module/Hotels!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Hotels
    java:global/directory/Hotels
    java:app/directory/Hotels
    java:module/Hotels

2015-11-11 10:14:04,635 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Suggestions in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Suggestions!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Suggestions
    java:app/directory/Suggestions!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Suggestions
    java:module/Suggestions!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Suggestions
    java:global/directory/Suggestions
    java:app/directory/Suggestions
    java:module/Suggestions

2015-11-11 10:14:04,637 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Airlines in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Airlines!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Airlines
    java:app/directory/Airlines!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Airlines
    java:module/Airlines!ru.zcts.travel.directory.info.boundary.Airlines
    java:global/directory/Airlines
    java:app/directory/Airlines
    java:module/Airlines

2015-11-11 10:14:04,646 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment.processors.EjbJndiBindingsDeploymentUnitProcessor] (MSC service thread 1-4) JNDI bindings for session bean named Cities in deployment unit deployment "directory.war" are as follows:

    java:global/directory/Cities!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Cities
    java:app/directory/Cities!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Cities
    java:module/Cities!ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.boundary.Cities
    java:global/directory/Cities
    java:app/directory/Cities
    java:module/Cities

2015-11-11 10:14:05,470 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0006: Starting Services for CDI deployment: directory.war
2015-11-11 10:14:05,524 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) WELD-000900: 2.2.14 (Final)
2015-11-11 10:14:05,604 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYWELD0009: Starting weld service for deployment directory.war
2015-11-11 10:14:05,921 INFO  [org.jboss.as.jpa] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYJPA0010: Starting Persistence Unit (phase 2 of 2) Service 'directory.war#default'
2015-11-11 10:14:06,505 INFO  [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL9Dialect
2015-11-11 10:14:06,511 INFO  [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
2015-11-11 10:14:06,666 INFO  [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2015-11-11 10:14:07,116 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYCLINF0002: Started directory.war#default.ru.zcts.travel.directory.location.entity.Location cache from hibernate container
2015-11-11 10:14:07,146 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) WFLYCLINF0002: Started pending-puts cache from hibernate container
2015-11-11 10:14:07,396 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000229: Running schema validator
2015-11-11 10:14:07,396 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2015-11-11 10:14:07,425 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.air_alliances
2015-11-11 10:14:07,426 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [image, created, name, id, updated, version, info]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,434 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.airline_names
2015-11-11 10:14:07,434 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [name, airline_id, locale]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,443 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.airlines
2015-11-11 10:14:07,444 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [image, crt, created, version, alliance_id, iata, low_cost, icao, id, updated, key, bsp, info]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,453 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.airplane_images
2015-11-11 10:14:07,454 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [airplane_id, media]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,463 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.airplane_seat_maps
2015-11-11 10:14:07,463 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [airplane_id, image, id, version]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,472 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.airplane_seats
2015-11-11 10:14:07,472 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [media_top, num, media_height, id, row, media_width, version, media_left, seat_map_id, service_class]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,480 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.airplanes
2015-11-11 10:14:07,481 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [created, airline_id, id, updated, version, key]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,489 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.areas_locations
2015-11-11 10:14:07,490 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [area_id, location_id]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,502 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.coach_images
2015-11-11 10:14:07,503 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [coach_id, media]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,514 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.coach_seat_maps
2015-11-11 10:14:07,515 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [coach_id, image, id, version]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,524 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.coach_seats
2015-11-11 10:14:07,525 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [media_top, num, media_height, id, media_width, version, media_left, seat_map_id]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,535 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.coaches
2015-11-11 10:14:07,536 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [railway_id, created, id, updated, version, key]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,544 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.hotel_chains
2015-11-11 10:14:07,545 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [image, created, name, id, updated, version, info]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,555 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.hotel_names
2015-11-11 10:14:07,555 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [hotel_id, name, locale]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,563 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.hotels
2015-11-11 10:14:07,564 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [hotel_book, image, chain_id, created, latitude, version, id, category, updated, key, city_id, longitude, info]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,572 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.localized_formal_names
2015-11-11 10:14:07,573 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [name, search_name, locale, location_id]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,581 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.localized_names
2015-11-11 10:14:07,582 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [name, search_name, locale, location_id]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,590 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.locations
2015-11-11 10:14:07,591 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [hotel_book, ufs, iso, latitude, type, time_zone, version, iata, province_id, icao, id, country_id, key, itransfer, city_id, longitude]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,603 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.rail_unions
2015-11-11 10:14:07,603 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [image, created, name, id, updated, version, info]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,612 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.railway_names
2015-11-11 10:14:07,613 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [railway_id, name, locale]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,621 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000261: Table found: public.railways
2015-11-11 10:14:07,622 INFO  [org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 77) HHH000037: Columns: [image, ufs, created, union_id, id, updated, version, key, info]
2015-11-11 10:14:07,882 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,883 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding provider class org.keycloak.SkeletonKeyContextResolver from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,884 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.JsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,884 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ThemeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,885 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.WelcomeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,885 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding class resource org.keycloak.services.resources.QRCodeResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,886 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding provider singleton org.keycloak.services.resources.ModelExceptionMapper from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,886 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.ServerVersionResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,887 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.RealmsResource from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,888 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Adding singleton resource org.keycloak.services.resources.admin.AdminRoot from Application class org.keycloak.services.resources.KeycloakApplication
2015-11-11 10:14:07,999 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /auth
2015-11-11 10:14:13,384 INFO  [org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) Deploying javax.ws.rs.core.Application: class ru.zcts.travel.directory.TravelDirectoryApplication$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy
2015-11-11 10:14:13,784 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) WFLYUT0021: Registered web context: /directory
2015-11-11 10:14:13,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 41) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "directory.war" (runtime-name : "directory.war")
2015-11-11 10:14:13,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 71) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "keycloak-server.war" (runtime-name : "keycloak-server.war")
2015-11-11 10:14:13,854 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "modeshape-webdav.war" (runtime-name : "modeshape-webdav.war")
2015-11-11 10:14:14,305 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0060: Http management interface listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990/management
2015-11-11 10:14:14,305 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0051: Admin console listening on http://127.0.0.1:9990
2015-11-11 10:14:14,305 INFO  [org.jboss.as] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0025: WildFly Full 9.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 1.0.1.Final) started in 24643ms - Started 870 of 1084 services (308 services are lazy, passive or on-demand)
```

Comment: As I found out it is problem in eclipse IDE. Changes which I make in Eclipse can to see only in Eclipse editor but it not take effect in the file system. If I edited source file in Notepad++,  the changes are saved on the server while application deploying.

Comment: I created .project file for Eclipse using 'gradle eclipse' command. Before this I added line "apply plugin: 'java'" in the build.gradle. After creating .project file I removed this line.

Comment: Consider using https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/red-hat-jboss-developer-studio with eclipse, works great for JBoss